# org-mode - how to ignore link syntax inside of src blocks?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, org-link

The link syntax `[[link]]` is parsed as an org-link inside of a source block, as shown in the code and figure below, where my mouse if placed on top of `[[2]]`.

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
[[2]]
#+end_src
```

[image]

This if fine in the example above, but consider a language like python. The link syntax is also valid python syntax:

```
#+begin_src python
x = np.array([[2]])
#+end_src
```

[image]

If I now toggle link display with `org-toggle-link-display`, then my python code is still valid, but reads as if it'd be wrong:

[image]

How could I tell org-mode to not parse links inside of org src-blocks?

---

*org version 9.5.4.
Emacs 29.0.50*

Comment: Not sure you can. I think you should report this with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: I tried but it seems my emails don't come through (at least not in the public list).

Comment: The entire fontification for org-mode is being rewritten based on the org parser (instead of the current regex framework). The rewrite effort should fix this when it lands